# Number of cards to deal to guarantee three from the same suit

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The minimum number of cards to be dealt from an arbitrarily shuffled deck of $52$ cards to guarantee that three cards are from some same suit is??

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Please show work or research.

Answer (score 10):

**Hint:** If your luck runs out, the first $8$ cards we choose will consist of $2$ of each suit. The answer is hence...